# Is it possible to put a varargs argument in the middle of the parameters list, and an optional argument last?

Tags: python, syntax, variadic-functions

This is possible syntactically, but is it possible practically?

```
def func(arg1, *args2, arg3 = None):
    ....
```

We can never access `arg3`, am I right? If so, why does Python allow this?

Answer (score 1):

What you have declared is a function with at least one positional parameter and one required keyword-only parameter.  You would call it as `func('arg', 1, 2, 3, 'whatever', arg3=2)` if you want to pass a value for `arg3`.  For example,

```
>>> def func(arg1, *args2, arg3=None):
...   print('arg1', arg1)
...   print('args2', args2)
...   print('arg3', arg3)
...
>>> func(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
arg1 1
args2 (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
arg3 None
>>> func(1, arg3=2)
arg1 1
args2 ()
arg3 2
>>>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this is possible only in Python 3.  Keyword-only arguments don't exist in Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can call it with arg3 argument. You need just to tell this explicitly:

```
func('arg1', 'some' 'values', 'that', 'will be', 'treated', 'as *arg2', arg3 = 'new value')
```

This way you will get your `arg3 = 'new value'`